# multiple senders, multiple receivers

Tags: chromecast

I guess I can have multiple senders talk to the same receiver.
But how is the "floor management" (who gets displayed) handled?

Now, say I have multiple screens (e.g. in a store). Can I stream the same content from a single sender to multiple Cast devices?

Arnaud

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast from one sender to multiple receivers at the same time; there can be only one **connected** device at a time on your sender side.

On the receiver, you can have **multiple devices** connected to it and how it handles that is dictated by your app; one app may not allow more than one concurrent connection; others can allow multiple ones (*this should be the norm unless there is a reason not to do it that way*).

e.g. a tictactoe game may only allow two players. When multiple devices are connected, how each device influences the TV screen is again up to the receiver.

In most cases, receivers do not distinguish who was there first and who joined next (*common use case for a typical media centric app*) but again, the receiver has the capability (*via its APIs*) to change that behavior (*for example, in a game, the first person joining/starting a game may have additional privileges over subsequent players*).
 If receiver doesn't discriminate against the order in which the senders joined, usually the last person who **casts** a content is the one who dictates what shows up on the TV.

Comment: Is it possible to have a Sender application that will allow you to connect to CC-1, cast some content, then connect to CC-2 and cast different content and so on? I need to be able to connect to several CC's, one after the other, to give them instructions (e.g. display custom text on a custom Receiver)

Comment: @Ali Can multiple devices communicate with the single receiver simultaneously?

Comment: Yes, it is a common scenario.

Comment: @AliNaddaf can we achieve like one sender(Mobile App) broadcast video streaming and multiple receiver eg, TV cast it?. any technologies or other ways?

Comment: Can I post multiple content streams? For example I have an app that lets you select 3 video files. I want all of them to play on the TV screen by splitting them 3 ways. Or lets say I have 4 video sources (cameras), how can I split screen 4 ways and show it on the TV.